# Crystal Reports + Asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, asp.net-2.0

I having a problem in crystal reports xi release 2 + visula studio 2005 with sp1

the error it's giving is this:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

on line 50:

```
<httpHandlers>
<add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

I dont know what to do, please help

Answer---> deploy the Crystal Reports .NET components to the web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go and check out this thread, seems a lot of other guys have had the same problem.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/b0fc930f-5fc8-4475-bfe7-ad56616e838d